# ruby gem issue uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Ok I'm not a pro at creating gems, but I tried my best and created this gem https://rubygems.org/gems/webpack_native/versions/0.2.0

This gem has generators and if I use it from the local folder (meaning the gem folder is in my computer) it works fine, if I type `rails g` in terminal it shows me the generators including my gem's generators

But using it from rubygems always give me an error `uninitialized constant WebpackNative`:

```
/home/mody/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@myapp/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:80:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant WebpackNative (NameError)
```

any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this happen but I get it to work after I installed devise gem and run

```
rails g
```

the output of the available generators shows up including my gem, and the generator itself is working.